# Synchronous I/O and Asynchronous I/O?

Tags: multithreading, asynchronous, synchronization

I know the explanation of these two I/O. However I did not get how "synchronous" definition relate to the explanation. For example.  "Synchronous" means "Occurring at the same time"Synchronous I/O means that if a thread invokes a I/O request, the thread would wait for I/O completion. So in this case, what and what are occurring at the same time? I really don't think "synchronous I/O" is a self-explainable  term.

Comment: It means "occurring at the same time".  Since I/O never occurs at the same time, there is only one way an I/O operation can be synchronous: the thread has to block and cannot resume running until the operation is completed.  So from the point of view of the logic in the program, and the programmer writing the code, it happened at the same time.   Greatly simplifies the code.   From the point of view of the user of the program however there was a noticeable delay.  Could be seconds on, say, a slow Internet connection, that makes not waiting for it attractive.

Comment: @HansPassant  Thanks for replying.  I still don't know  what and what are occurring at same time.  I/O request and I/O completion ?